# Integration method - hint please

Tags: integration

As part of a homework assignment, I have to determine whether the following integral converges or not.

$$\int_0 ^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2 + \ln(1+x)}dx$$

Could anyone please give me some hints on how to solve the integral? I've tried substituting various expression but that hasn't really done anything for me...

Comment: Bound it above or below by a different integral which converges or diverges, respectively. You might need to split up the domain of integration first.

Comment: You can use the limit comparison test with $\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2}$

Comment: @Dylan What happens around $0$?

Comment: Right. Well at least you can do that for $\int_1^{\infty}$

Comment: For the other bound there's $\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+x}$

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha disagrees](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt(x)%2F(x%5E2%2Bx)+dx+from+0+to+inf)

Comment: @Dylan But $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2 + \ln(1+x)} \ge \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+x}$

Comment: @EugenCovaci Doesn't matter. You can scale it by a constant to make it bigger, since the limit of the two functions is $1$

Comment: @Dylan Then scale it, make an answer.

Comment: Sure, I was just going to give a hint, but might as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mattos and Dylan have noted, the first step is to split the integral:
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2 + \log(1+x)}\, \mathrm{d}x
=
\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2 + \log(1+x)}\, \mathrm{d}x}_{=:I_1} + \underbrace{\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2 + \log(1+x)}\, \mathrm{d}x}_{=:I_2}$$
I am, however, unsatisfied by Dylan's $\sim$ (it is not incorrect; I just find it aesthetically unsatisfactory in this context).  For my own taste, I would like to see the estimates made a bit more explicit.  Thus the following two arguments:

- For $I_1$, note that the logarithm is concave down (this can be made rigorous by examining the second derivative, but [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fzlu94dpi1) should be convincing enough in this context).  From this, it follows that the line through the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,\log(2))$ (for example) is entirely below the graph of $\log(1+x)$ on the interval $[0,1]$.  This line is given by $y = \log(2)x$, and so on this interval, we have
  $$ x^2 + \log(1+x)
  \ge x^2 + \log(2)x
  \ge \log(2) x, $$
  where the last inequality follows from the fact that $x^2 > 0$ for all 
  $x$.  But then
  $$ \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2 + \log(1+x)}
  \le \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log(2) x}
  = \frac{1}{\log(2)} x^{-\frac{1}{2}}. $$
  Finally, we can integrate and obtain
  \begin{align} I_1
  &\le \lim_{t\to 0} \int_{t}^{1} \frac{1}{\log(2)} x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x \\
  &= \frac{1}{\log(2)} \lim_{t\to 0} \left( \frac{1}{2} x^{\frac{1}{2}} \right]_{x=t}^{1} \\
  &= \frac{1}{\log(2)}\lim_{t\to 0} \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{t} \right) \\
  &= \frac{1}{2\log(2)}
  < \infty.
  \end{align}
- For $I_2$, note that when $x > 1$, we have $\log(1+x) > 0$.  It then follows that
  $$ \log(1+x) > 0
  \implies x^2 + \log(1+x) > x^2
  \implies \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2 + \log(1+x)} < \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2} = x^{-\frac{3}{2}}.$$
  But $x^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ is integrable on the interval $[1,\infty)$.  Indeed, comparing to the term $I_2$, we have
  $$ I_2 \le
  \lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{1}^{t} x^{-\frac{3}{2}} \,\mathrm{d}x
  = \lim_{t\to \infty} \left( -\frac{1}{2} x^{-\frac{1}{2}} \right]_{x=1}^{t}
  = \lim_{t\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)
  = \frac{1}{2} < \infty.
  $$

Combining the two inequalities above, we conclude that
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2 + \ln(1+x)}\, \mathrm{d}x
= I_1 + I_2
< \infty. $$

Comment: My answer was more of a hint, not supposed to be a rigorous answer. The $\sim$ is more of an intuition. We find an appropriate asymptotic expression  and then turn it into a bound by varying the multiplicative constant.

Comment: I do appreciate the extra work though.

Comment: @Dylan I didn't mean to disparage your work at all---as I said, it is entirely correct (I even upvoted it).  I'm just more comfortable with explicit estimates.

Comment: I didn't see it as disparaging. I am glad you were willing to go further than I was. My comment was to whomever maybe encountering this post in the future. I went into it assuming the limit comparison test was common knowledge, so that's my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

As @Mattos said, it does help to break integral into two parts
$$ \int_0^{\infty} = \int_0^1 +\int_1^{\infty} $$

For $x\to \infty$ we have $x^2 + \ln(1+x) \sim x^2$, so

$$ \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+\ln(1+x)}\ dx < \int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2} \ dx < \infty $$

For $x\to 0$ we have $ x^2 + \ln(1+x) \sim x $, so

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+\ln(1+x)}\ dx < \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}\ dx < \infty $$

We can also compare
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+\ln(1+x)}\ dx \sim \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+x}\ dx < \infty $$
but that's not quite as simple of course

Comment: How do you prove: $\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+\ln(1+x)}\ dx < \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}\ dx$?

Comment: From the Taylor series, $ \ln(1+x) \approx x - \frac{x^3}{3} $ for $|x| \ll 1$

Comment: You can also show that both $x^2 + \ln(1+x)$ and $x$ are increasing on $[0,1]$, and the former is larger than the latter at $x=1$

Comment: The fact that the former is larger than the latter at x=1 doesn't imply $x^2 + \ln(1+x) \gt x$, even if both are increasing functions

Comment: an exact proof isn't too important here. We can show that $$ x^2 + \ln(1+x) > cx $$ for some arbritary constant $c$. As $c$ can be arbitrarily small, an upper bound exists.

Comment: The nice thing about asymptotic behavior is exact values do not matter. The proof doesn't require an exact bound, just that one such bound exists. As long as two functions have the same growth rate, they will also have the same convergence, regardless of which way the inequality sign points.

Comment: See also [Limit comparison Theorem for Improper integrals](https://services.math.duke.edu/~cbray/Stanford/2003-2004/Math%2042/limitcomp.pdf)

Comment: I was saying that your argument: "the former is larger than the latter at x=1 ..." is invalid, that's all.

Comment: You're right, that was not the best way to prove it.